# memory leak in pushViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, memory-leaks

I'm new to memory management, and i've searched for similar topics, but didn't find such simple example causing memory leak. I'm testing my application with Instruments and it says I have memory leak of 144 Bytes in pushViewController.

rootViewController:

```
- (IBAction)optionsAction
{
    optionsViewController *ovc = [[optionsViewController alloc] init];
    // MEMORY LEAK 100.0%
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ovc animated:YES]; 
    [ovc release];
}
```

optionsViewController.h

```
@interface optionsViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {
    UISlider *volumeSlider;
    UISwitch *soundSwitch;
    SystemSoundID SSID;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *soundSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;
@property (assign) SystemSoundID SSID;

@end
```

optionsViewController.m

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [volumeSlider release];
    [soundSwitch release];
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(self.SSID);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Have you any idea what could be the reason of this leak? Can you say where should I search for the problem, rootViewController or optionsViewController?

Comment: Check `init` function of `optionsViewController` controller .

Comment: Init is deafult: 
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think [AppSoundEngine](https://github.com/CocoaMiners/AppSoundEngine) could simplify your life :) It is objective-c wrapper for system sounds, easy to use. You can handle sound play competence to dedicated class. Your view controller would be less stressed :)